# is focus selector is not working with onfocusout function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have three textbox 1, 2, 3

If textbox1 is empty it should show an alert the textbox1 is empty and textbox1 should be on focus

If textbox2 is empty, I Should be able to go to textbox1 but if textbox3 is clicked it should show an alert that The textbox2 is empty

If textbox1 and textbox2 is not empty I can focus textbox3.

My code

```
<form>
  Text 1 <input type="text" id="text1" onfocusout="check1()" autofocus><br/><br/>
  Text 2 <input type="text" id="text2" onfocusout="check2()"><br/><br/>
  Text 3 <input type="text" id="text3" >
</form>

<script>
    function check1() {
        var x=$("#text1").val();
         
         if(x==""){
            alert("The textbox 1  is empty");
            setTimeout(function() {
                $("#text1").focus();
             }, 100);
            return false;
         }else{
                $("#text2").focus();
         }
    }

    function check2() {
        var y=$("#text2").val();
        
         if($("#text1").is(":focus")){
            $("#text1").focus();
         }else if(y=="" ){
            alert("The textbox 2 is empty")
         }else{
            $("#text3").focus();
         }
    }
</script>
```

check1() function works, check2() has some issues, How to correct this

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead validating it on `focusout` you can use `focusin` event.

```
<form>
  Text 1 <input type="text" id="text1" onfocusin="check(this.id)" autofocus><br/><br/>
  Text 2 <input type="text" id="text2" onfocusin="check(this.id)"><br/><br/>
  Text 3 <input type="text" id="text3" onfocusin="check(this.id)">
</form>
<script>
    function check(id) {
        if(id != "text1" && $("#text1").val() == "")
        {   
            alert("The textbox 1 is empty");
            $("#text1").focus();
        }
        else if(id == "text3" && $("#text2").val() == "")
        {   
            alert("The textbox 2 is empty");
            $("#text2").focus();
        }
    }
</script>
```